# How can I "reboot into" the non-default operating system in a dual-boot configuration?

Tags: windows, dual-boot, grub2

When I need to use Windows, I:

1. Reboot
2. Wait for the Grub boot menu to appear
3. Choose the Windows menu item in Grub

Is there a way to just "reboot into" Windows so that I don't have to stay at the computer and guide it to the right operating system? i.e. Can I set the default menu item in Grub for just *the next* boot?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This tutorial solves this problem: http://www.webupd8.org/2010/10/how-to-reboot-in-windows-from-ubuntu.html

From the aforementioned tutorial:

> 3. Now to reboot Ubuntu in Windows or some other OS, run the following
>   command: `sudo grub-reboot X`
>
> where X is the menuentry position
>   (starting with 0 as the first entry)
>   of the OS you want to restart in from
>   the GRUB menu. So if Windows is the
>   4th option in the GRUB menu, you would
>   run "sudo grub-reboot 3". You can also
>   use the exact menu entry instead of
>   the menuentry position (like "Windows
>   7 (on /dev/sda1)") but entering just a
>   number should be easier to remember.
>   **The grub-reboot will set the default
>   boot entry for the next boot only**.

Answer (score -2):

Just edit these two lines:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

and then choose windows OS from the grub menu. it will start automatically whenever you start your PC.

if you want add '0' to 'GRUB_TIMEOUT=' line ,and the menu will disapear :

> GRUB_TIMEOUT=0

Full answer: [How can I undo the effects of grub-reboot?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/14745/how-can-i-undo-the-effects-of-grub-reboot)

PS: if you want to show the menu again, you have to press SHIF key during booting your PC

Comment: This is not what I want to do. As my original question indicates, I only want to set the default menu item in Grub for just *the next* boot.