# How can I undo the effects of grub-reboot?

Tags: grub2

I accidentally ran `sudo grub-reboot 4` ([background](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8803/how-can-i-reboot-into-the-non-default-operating-system-in-a-dual-boot-configura)) twice in a row, and now GRUB permanently boots to the fourth menu item.

How can I restore the default boot behavior?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [grub-set-default](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/Invoking-grub_002dset_002ddefault.html) command.
For example, assuming you want the first grub entry to be your default:

`sudo grub-set-default 0`

Comment: Or you can clear all this state entirely with 'sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv unset prev_saved_entry; sudo grub-editenv /boot/grub/grubenv unset saved_entry'.  (That's slightly lower-level, though.)

Answer (score 3):

Open Terminal and type:

```
cd /etc/default/
```

Backup your file:

```
sudo cp grub grub.backup
```

Edit your file:

```
gksudo gedit grub
```

Add this line before the `GRUB_DEFAULT=?` line:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
```

and change this line to:

```
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
```

Save, close and then run this:

```
sudo update-grub
```

Next time, whenever you choose an OS from your `grub` menu it will be the default one until you choose another one, and so on.

Your first lines will look like these:

```
GRUB_SAVEDEFAULT=true
GRUB_DEFAULT=saved
#GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
GRUB_TIMEOUT=6
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
# ...
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion, but this is not the default behavior I want to restore. I want GRUB to always boot to the first menu item.

Answer (score 1):

It is working , ...anyway.

the first choice in the grub2 menu is '0' the second one is '1' and so on.......

so your file looks like:

> GRUB_DEFAULT=0
>    #GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
>   GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
>   GRUB_TIMEOUT=10
>   GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""
>   GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""

.................
......................

Comment: Please only use the *Post Your Answer* button for new, different answers. You should use the *edit* button to modify your original answer if you need to add additional information.