# Boot to Windows option? Similar to bootcamp

Tags: grub2, bluetooth

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How can I “reboot into” the non-default operating system in a dual-boot configuration?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/8803/how-can-i-reboot-into-the-non-default-operating-system-in-a-dual-boot-configura)

I'm using a wireless keyboard via bluetooth and therefore cannot use it in grub, so I have to plug in an USB keyboard everytime I want to boot into Windows. AFAK Apple solved this problem by adding adding functions such as "Boot to MacOSX" in the Boot Camp control panel (iMacs come with Bluetooth mice and keyboard) so I was wondering weather it's possible to tell grub to boot Windows next time (and maybe even tell it from Windows to boot Linux next time)

Answer (score 5):

`sudo grub-reboot X` where X is the menu entry position (starting with 0 as the first entry)

Comment: Now I just need a reliable way to figure out the menu entry number..

Comment: Just read that I also can type in the exact name of the menu entry. So how can I change it that I just can type grub-reboot win?

Comment: sudo vi /boot/grub/menu.lst (or replace vi with editor of choice)

Comment: Actually, I've just noticed I'm behind the times... Check http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1195275 if you're running 9.10 or later version of Ubuntu

Comment: now wouldnt it be nice if ubiquity let us do it at install time ( much like anaconda)

Comment: @Wolfger First they moved it to /boot/grub/grub.cfg or something. Second I quote the second line of this file: # DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE

Comment: nothing happens on grub-reboot